# Check for int or string from file

Tags: php, arrays, file, sorting, types

I'm trying to open an input file containing a variety of data type. Something like this:

```
Woof 
50 
Meow 
30 
//...
```

And I'm not quite sure how to do it. I've googled for ways to do it and I found something like `ctype_digit`, `is_digit`, and `is_string`. I tested them out and I'm still not getting the expected result.

This is the code snippet I am using:

```
// Sorts the array by requested data type
function sortArray($anArray, $dataType){

    $array_string = array();
    $array_int = array();

    foreach ($anArray as $element){
        if (ctype_digit($element)){
            array_push($array_int, $element);
        }
        elseif (ctype_alpha($element)){
            array_push($array_string, $element);
        }
    }

    if ($dataType == "int"){
        return $array_int;
    }
    elseif ($dataType == "String"){
        return $array_string;
    }
} // end function sortArray($anArray, $dataType)
```

Can anyone help point out why it's not working?

Comment: *why it's not working?* Do you get any errors? What does not working mean?

Comment: PHP still thinks they all are strings.

Comment: Then either show us your **full** and **real** code or look at the answers below maybe one answer solves your problem

Comment: I apologize for not responding right away. I was away from my desk, of where my web server resides. I am back at the desk right now, and checking out the suggestions now. I'll let you know what turns out. Again... I apologize for any frustration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your function seems way to complicated. Just filter all other values which you don't want with [`array_filter()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) out like this:

```
<?php

    //As an example to get the data from the file nice and quick
    $lines = array_map("trim", file("test.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES));

    function filterArrayByType($arr, $type = "int") {
        return array_filter($arr, ($type === "int"?"ctype_digit":"ctype_alpha"));
    }

    $result = filterArrayByType($lines, "string"); //"int"
    print_r($result);

?>
```

output:

```
Array ( [0] => Woof [2] => Meow )  //Array ( [1] => 50 [3] => 30 )
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you! :)  Could I please have you tell me how array_map("trim", file) works? I would like to know so I can keep in my mind for the future. :)

Comment: @RobertP Yeah for sure: So basically with `file()` I get the file as array where every line is 1 element in the array. But to get the `ctype_*` functions to work I have to remove spaces at the start and the end of each element. So here I use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) Which basically loops through each element and uses the trim function on it.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful tip and solution to my dilemma :)

Answer (score 0):

is_string() and is_float() will give true or false if argument is string or float. (float can be 12.21)

- **is_string() - Find whether the type of a variable is string**
- **is_float() - Finds whether the type of a variable is float**
- is_int() - Find whether the type of a variable is integer
- is_bool() - Finds out whether a variable is a boolean
- is_object() - Finds whether a variable is an object
- is_array() - Finds whether a variable is an array

Remember that a number can also be a string. its all about how you write it. So is_string must be the last in a row of is_ checks.

```
is_string('23') = true
is_string(23) = false
is_string('23.5') = true
is_string(23.5) = false
```